# Directory API query "NOT EQUAL"?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am trying to query the Directory api for users with orgUnitPath=/ but not equal to any sub OUs.

I have read the following and it doesn't mention any "NOT EQUAL","!=", or "<>" operators.
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### "NOT EQUAL" is not part of the [supported operators](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users#operators) for the Directory API

So, unfortunately, your only option to list all users and then filter the "NON EQUAL" values programatically within your code.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am doing, but I was hoping for a more efficient way rather than looping through 100k records to find 10. Is there anywhere I can go to suggest a modification to the API?

Comment: Yes! You can file a feature request on [Goole's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).